# upload and display multiple images for one product?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a basic ecommerce website using PHP/MYSQL. I just need to know how I can upload multiple images for a product and then display them in the products page.
as for uploading multiple images, I don't want to use uploadify or open source codes like that. i rather have 3-4 extra fileupload fields if possible at all!

And I cannot get my head around the displaying the images (multiple images for 1 product). I really don't understand how it should work! so any advice on simple terms would be appreciated.

Currently I can only upload 1 image per product.

Here is what I have so far, please ignore the mysql queries in the first file as this is a not going live yet until I have converted the mysql to mysqli. Just need to get functions sorted first:

> **upload.php**

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
        $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="add.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, quantity, details, category, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$quantity','$details','$category',now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    header("location: add.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

> **product.php**  <<< this is the page that displays the product details and image.

```
<?php 
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "config/connect.php"; 
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    // Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product 
    // details, if no then exit this script and give message why
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $quantity = $row["quantity"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         }

    } else {
        echo "That item does not exist.";
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
    exit();
}

?>

<table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="300" rowspan="5" align="right" valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;"><img src="inventory_images/<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg" width="300" height="450" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /></td>
    <td width="126" height="106">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="274"><h3 style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:1.8em;"><?php echo $product_name; ?></h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="120">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $details; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="110">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:1.8em;">Price: £<?php echo $price; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="font-family:Times New Roman; font-size:1.8em;">Quantity Left: <?php echo $quantity; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in this code that tries to store one image in the database, let alone multiple ones.

Comment: @Jessica, WELL You couldn't be more wrong. take a look at this: `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");`

Comment: @Jessica, store images where? they get stored in the inventory_images folder and they get renamed fine and they also get displayed on the product page fine. its just one per product at the moment.

Comment: if i were you, i would use another table... product_files (product_id, filename) and ensure filenames are unique.

Comment: @user2953877 Ah, nah technically Jessica is correct. There is a difference between "moving a file" and "storing it in the DB".

Comment: @patricksweeney, ah, i understand now. apologies to Jessica.

Comment: @SirDarius, shall i set the product_id to VARCHAR in the mysql?

Comment: i assumed the products table had an id as primary key... better to use numeric ids than varchars to avoid wasting space in the product_files table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the way you are currently doing it isn't really setup for multiple photos since you aren't storing a reference to the photo in the database. You are simply renaming the image to the primary key of the product. So you will need to either do something like 1_1.jpg 1_2.jpg or you will need to create a database table that stores the filename and the product id so you can have a one to many relationship.

As for uploading more images just add more file inputs to your form.

And for displaying you will need to either pull records from the photo db table or use `glob()` to find all the files that start with the primary key + '_'.

Also FYI mysql functions should no longer be used as they are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the mysql function is deprecated. thats why I said please ignore it as i am going to convert it to mysqli once the features are ready!

Comment: I don't really want to save the images in the mysql database as that is not a good practice! so would you please be able to guide me on how to rename the images to 1_1.jpg, 2_1.jpg according to my code?

Comment: I'm not saying to store the images in the db I'm saying create a table that stores the file name and product id.

Comment: I got you now. so which one do you think is best?

Comment: Also, what I don't understand is this. lets say I have created a table in the mysql that stores the filename and the product id! now lets say I want to upload multiple images for one product, how can I save the name of the products in one mysql column(filename). i can store 1 name but what happens when there are multiple images? I'm totally lost!

Comment: You add multiple records.

Comment: any chance of a quick and dirty code example so i understand it better?

Comment: Example code for what? You already have all the basic code above you just need to possibly add a mysql insert if you choose to go that route and a couple more `move_uploaded_file()` function calls.

Comment: thats the thing... I cannot upload more than 1 image! no matter how many `move_uploaded_file()` functions.

Comment: Do you have multiple file inputs on your form? What are the names on each of them?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 file inputs. their name is `fileField`. and I have this code in my PHP: `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");` I also tried it this way : `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField2']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname2");` with `$newname2 = "$pid.jpg";` and still doesn't upload multiple images. it only uploads 1 image.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it gave me a clue. Thanks a ton.

Comment: because $pid is going to be the same for both since that is your product id, you are uploading both but then the second one is probably overwriting the first. Change it to `$newname2 = "{$pid}_2.jpg";`